# Move Magento 1.9 to new server, but all pages give 404

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, magento-1.9

I am trying to move Magento 1.9 to new server, but all pages give 404, my steps was

1. Copied and installed Database and files on the new server
2. Fixed connections on the local.xml file
3. Reset the usecured and secured base url from the core_config_data
4. Cleared all files in var/cache var/session

[image]

Comment: Have you configured `MAGE_RUN_CODE` and `MAGE_RUN_TYPE` environment variables on the new server?

Comment: please check in .htaccess file

Comment: How do you solved your this issue ? I am getting the same problem when move magento 1.9 from ols server to new one based on ubuntu 20:04. thanks for your support.